# Computer Not Recognizing Hard Drive Previously Used In Storage Space Pool

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, formatting, storage-spaces

So I previously had an external hard drive that was used in a windows storage space pool, but that computer broke and I can no longer use it.

So I now have a new computer, but because the hard drive was part of a storage pool previously it doesn't recognize it.

I figured I could go back in and reformat it, but this is not the case. Device Manager recognizes it, but no other partition tool I've tried doesn't recognize it (including disk part). I just don't know what to do at this point.

Edit: Disk Management does not recognize it either.

Comment: What about the standard, Windows native, Disk Management? What does it (or doesn't) let you do (right-click menu)? Please [edit] and update the question.

Comment: Have you tried DISKPART ? Run > CMD (or PowerShell) -> DISKPART -> list disk

Comment: *Disk Management does not recognize it either* Does not recognize what, the drive itself? In that case there isn't any software for that. You need to find out where the problem is, the drive itself or the computer. Or it does show up there but you can't format it, for some reason?

Comment: @SamAndrew81 The OP mentioned they already tried DiskPart.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia The device is recognized within device management, but nowhere else

Comment: How is the drive connected in the new computer? Internally (SATA) or USB? You need to start ruling out possible causes but there's a chance that drive is dead. And, either way, nothing to do with storage spaces.

Comment: What if you boot a Windows 10 install USB. Then see if the disk shows up in the partition creation phase and see if you can delete it. If it does, you could then delete it, cancel the install, boot back into Windows and try to use Disk Management to reformat it.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia USB, tried switching ports

Comment: Well, can't you try internally and/or in another computer? That could possibly rule out the enclosure or cable you're using (and that information should have been in the question from the start, we can't guess what you have, and troubleshooting is different because USB implies that additional hardware is at play).